# Same method for multiple controls when using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, caliburn.micro, relaycommand

In WPF MVVM application, I need same functionality for multiple controls - for example certain button does same thing as certain menu item. It is piece of cake with MVVM Light's RelayCommand, but I am now using Caliburn.Micro, where almost everything is based on conventions. So two controls can not have same `x:Name="AddItem"`, which is used by CM to determine method for executing in ViewModel. Is there any **simple** way to solve this?

Comment: sure don't name them and bind what you need normally... use `cal:Message.Attach="YourMethod()"` to call the method on the viewmodel bound to the current Datacontext.  ContextMenus can get tricky due to visualtree limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's simple, but verbose. You need to use the "long format". Let's say you have one method `IncrementCount` on your ViewModel:

```
// Handling event
public void IncrementCount()
{
    Count++;
}
```

And your View has:

```
<Button Name="ButtonOne">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="IncrementCount" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>

<Button Name="ButtonTwo">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="IncrementCount" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Both buttons will call your `IncrementCount` method.

#### EDIT

Add these namespaces

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

You may see this [Caliburn starting project](https://github.com/feliperomero3/CaliburnMicroTutorial) using the snippets above.